# jquery.form ajaxSubmit outputs an error with multipart form

Tags: jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

When use `jquery.form (latest)` with `jquery.1.5.2` (I cant' change this) and a multi part form.

```
ERROR:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery-1.5.2.js:593
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/N8Knq/16/

I really need to determine why this only happens with multi-part forms

**JAVSCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#my_form').ajaxSubmit({
        success:function(response)
        {
           console.log(response);
        },
        dataType:'json'
    });                  
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="my_form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="my_text" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>​
```

​

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the latest version of that plugin leverages methods exclusive to jQuery 1.7+. You'll notice that **also** updating to the latest jQuery library will properly show the object in the console instead of an error.

[Go ahead, try it.](http://jsfiddle.net/N8Knq/17/)

Apparently I can't link without providing some code anymore, so here's some code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#my_form').ajaxSubmit({
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
        },
        dataType:'json'
    });                  
});
```

​

Comment: The plugin says in the comments that it is compatible with jquery 1.5 or higher. Do you know where I can find older versions of this plugin to try?

Answer (score 0):

I went through the github repo and found version 2.60 working with jquery 1.5.2. I tried about 10 different versions.